# Matrix doesn't pass as positive definite

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a 4x4 matrix which I believe should pass as positive definite however using is.positive.definite(), it is evaluating to false. When I use nearPD() to compute the nearest positive definite matrix, the resulting matrix evaluates as positive definite with is.positive.definite(), but looks the same.

The matrix looks like this

```
 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1
 0 0 1 1
```

Where x'Mx should evaluate to (x1+x2)^2 + (x3+x4)^2 which seems to satisfy the positive definite condition.

Anyway, here is the code. Does anyone know if there is anything I am missing here?

```
library(Matrix)
library(matrixcalc)

D = rbind(c(1,1,0,0),c(1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1),c(0,0,1,1))

##evaluates false
is.positive.definite(D)

d = nearPD(D)$mat
d = matrix(d, nrow = 4)

## looks the same as D
d

##but evaluates to positive definite
is.positive.definite(d)
```

Comment: If x1 = -x2 and x3 = x4 = 0 then the quadratic form evaluates to 0.

Comment: in which package is the function `is.positive.definite` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix is not positive definite. [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix):

In linear algebra, a symmetric n × n real matrix M is said to be positive definite if zTMz is positive **for every non-zero column vector z of n real numbers**.

Consider the vector (-1,1,-1,1). It is nonzero and only contains real numbers.

But (-1+1)^2+(-1+1)^2=0, which is not greater than zero. So the matrix is not positive definite. The matrix is *positive semi-definite*, though.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It looks like nearPD is tweaking the matrix entries slightly enough that the entries are still displaying as 1. (D-d) is evaluating to some small numbers though.